# Mysql - Data without spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to import the follow data (without separators between fields):

```
20232045001100000700002769T011998-01-22 0001-01-01 0001-01-01  0      1998-01-22-13.48.03.363642
20168752001100000700037166T011997-10-21 0001-01-01 0001-01-01  0      1997-10-21-19.00.50.529609
20195936001100000700793006T011997-11-18 0001-01-01 0001-01-01  0      1997-11-18-17.59.30.518192
```

and this is the structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla008` (
  `numclien` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `centidad` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `coficina` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `digcontr` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ccuenta` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `clainter` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `secinter` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fealrela` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `space1` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fechape` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `space2` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fecancel` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `peyestat` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `indaviso` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `iugestor` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pehstamp` varchar(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `indcoext` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(I have to put all in VARCHAR for test)
Then, I want import this data with this sentence SQL

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/mis/RBA/RBACalidad/Entradas/PEBC.PEFD.FIX.UNLO.TABLA008.D1140813.TXT'
INTO TABLE tabla008
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But, when run it, the result is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClpyE.png]

And the result must be:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NYou.png]

I don't understand why this is the result, if my sentence SQL is fine!

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide what should be the output? with the image you provided I can only speculate that that is due to the length of you variables.

Comment: @Alexander You should learn more about MySQL `datatypes`. There are specific types of data for each different data and instead you're giving everything the type `varchar` which is **REALLY BAD** considering the data you have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't want to do, but I did.

I use this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/mis/RBA/RBACalidad/Entradas/TABLA008.D1140813.TXT'
INTO TABLE tabla008
(@row)
SET numclien=SUBSTRING(@row,1,8),
entidad=SUBSTRING(@row,9,4),
oficina=SUBSTRING(@row,13,4),
digcontrol=SUBSTRING(@row,17,2),
cuenta=SUBSTRING(@row,19,8),
clainter=SUBSTRING(@row,27,1),
secinter=SUBSTRING(@row,28,2),
fealrela=SUBSTRING(@row,30,10),
space1=SUBSTRING(@row,40,1),
fechape=SUBSTRING(@row,41,10),
space2=SUBSTRING(@row,51,1),
fecancel=SUBSTRING(@row,52,10),
space3=SUBSTRING(@row,62,1),
peyestat=SUBSTRING(@row,63,1),
indaviso=SUBSTRING(@row,64,1),
iugestor=SUBSTRING(@row,65,6),
pehstamp=SUBSTRING(@row,71,26),
indcoext=SUBSTRING(@row,97,1);
```

It isn't a elegant solution, but it works

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two-fold:

- the import file doesn't fit to the tables column definition
- your load statement doesn't consider the proper syntax of the csv file

If you have a definition "`FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''`" that means there is no field separator at all. Thus, the columns length apply:

Your row and the fields length:

```
   20232045001100000700002769T011998-01-22 0001-01-01 
           ^  split into "numclien"
                           ^split in to "centidad"
   ...
```

If your CSV contains tabs (\t), change to

```
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

which would be the normal csv syntax. As of your example, the file contains one or more spaces as field separator. You might test

```
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

but I expect this to produce empty fields in the rows. It's better to prcess the file and replace sequences of spaces by tab.

And definitively the csv should fit to the columns length or the columns should have an according type set (like date, timestamp etc, see comments above)

Comment: Hi

I put VARCHAR() for all fields as test.

The input I can't modify. I have verify that the import file yes fit to the tables column definition, both are 96 of lenght.

I put FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' because just there isn't separatores.

I have try with FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' but the result is other (bad)

Thanks

Comment: Well, some are hopeless, this won't work as long as you can't distinguish between the fields either by a separator or by proper length; and as long as the input is not hardcoded in the bios of your server you *can* modify - and even if would be there you could make a copy ...